# Firefox ignoring link colour CSS

Tags: css, firefox

I've set the link colour to Black.  It works fine in IE8 but not in Firefox 7.

[image]

As you can see, all the links are a blue colour and not black. You can see the CSS on the right hand side in Firebug.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: working fine in FF 7 http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to just try "a" instead of a:link. Is there a chance the link has been visited? If so that may explain why it's blue (it would be taking in the a:visited styles).

Comment: I'm an idiot, there was a a:visited tag hidden in my css file and that's what it was.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the firefox settings dialog:

```
-> tab: "Content"
-> group: "Fonts & Colors" 
-> button: "Colors" 
-> checkbox: "Allow pages to choose their own color, instead of my selections above"
```

Maybe this option is disabled in your browser.

(My firefox is not set to english, so the text may vary)